# Are RGB values encoded/recorded in raw LAS/pointcloud data?

Tags: las, point-cloud, rgb

RGB info in the pointcloud: Is this always from a post-processing step (e.g. using imagery overlay techniques to do so) or does it in some cases come from the machine/sensor which recorded the LAS?

Answer (score 2):

We can distinguish 3 cases I think (maybe somebody may add information to this answer)

If the data source is a single wavelength laser the RGB values are necessarily coming from a post processing step. The point cloud is colorized with aerial photography for example.

If the data source is a multispectral laser (i.e. 3 lasers with 3 wavelenght) the point cloud usually comes in 3 files, one per channel, or in one file but each channel is recorded individually. So RGB is necessarily a post-processing step because each point is recorded from a single wavelength laser.

If the point cloud is a photogrammetry point-cloud, then the RGB are, more or less, native colors. I'm saying more or less because there is some data processing anyway.

Comment: thanks @JRR for posting these!